# Appium locating child element with specific value in Java

Tags: java, android, xpath, appium

I am struggling with a navigation drawer on a native Android app.

So there are 11 elements in the drawer, 9 are visible, for the rest you have to scroll down.

[Appium Inspector view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5j2P.png)

those elements contain 2 child elements, first - imageView, second - textView element.

[Appium Inspector view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFaFT.png)

what I want to do, is create a method to iterate through the visible drawer elements in search for the element with a specific name and then tap on it, if the elements is invisible, I will scroll the drawer down/up and then repeat the iteration.

So I need a for loop to iterate through textView elements, locate the one I need using a text attribute and then click on the parent element of this textView.

However I'm struggling with properly locating the elements using xpath and Appium can not seem to find them.

Can anyone help me to understand how to specify xpath dynamically so I can iterate through the elements?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like I have below. This uses the PageObject model, along with Selenium and Appium. It takes advantage of the uiAutomator, rather than Xpath.

```
public class PageObjectXYZ {

    private AndroidDriver driver;

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView")")
    private List<MobileElements> someTextViews;

    public PageObjectXYZ(AndroidDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    public void clickTheOneIWant(String option){
        for(MobileElement me: someTextViews){
            if(me.getAttribute("text").equals(option)){
                this.driver.tap(1, me, 1000);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want the quick and dirty using xpath, then something like(some assembly may be required):

```
String x = "//RecyclerView/RelativeLayout/RelativeLayout/TextView";
String y = "//RecyclerView/RelativeLayout/RelativeLayout";

Android driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);

Arraylist<MobileElements> arrayTextViews = driver.findElementsByXpath(x);
Arraylist<MobileElements> arrayParentElements = driver.findElementsByXpath(y);

for(int i = 0; i < arrayTextViews.size(); i++){
    if(arrayTextViews.get(i).getText().equals("text I want")){
        arrayParentElements.get(i).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: In regards to understanding xpath dynamically,

Comment: , "//" means to start anywhere in the xml. If you want to use a static path from the root element, start with "/". You want to specify which element to navigate to first, in you example I can't see the highest root element, perhaps it is "/DrawerLayout". You can start further into the document by using "//RecyclerView" to start the xpath. Then, use "/" to step down elements. "//RecyclerView/RelativeLayout[1] would return the first RelativeLayout element. You could always just add the parameter you'd like. Ex. //TextView[text()='foo']

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Where can I read more about adding parameters to xpath like //TextView[text()='foo']  ? 

Is there also a way to locate a parent element of a child element using xpath or any other locator?

Comment: As for your example, I'm not sure how to use uiAutomator locators. I've tried googling it and haven't found much useful information on the usage of the locator and my attempts at finding an element using uiAutomator were unsuccessful. 

Your example is good, but it lacked one thing I needed, to scroll down if the element is not found. However I have almost solved this on my own. 

Do you know where I could learn about using uiAutomator locators etc.? Would be very helpful, I've read they're quite powerful and provide a lot of options for locating elements.

Comment: And aren't you supposed to have escape character for quotes in the locator:

@AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView")") ? For the className

Comment: Yea, the escape characters didn't copy/paste like they should've. In regards to a uiAUtomator tutorial, google has a good one(although, as with all tutorials google, you will need to dedicate 30 minutes to an hour to get the overall picture, as Google doesn't like to make it easy by giving diverse examples). https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html . The only difference being, you have to pass the AndroidFindBy a string command, so that will execute.

Comment: Example, the Google tutorial uses the code: UiObject cancelButton = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector()
        .text("Cancel"))
        .className("android.widget.Button"));     Whereas, you want to pass the string: @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().text(\"Cancel\")"

Comment: For scrolling purposes, this might assist.          "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView(resourceId("com.package.name:id/element_name"))")"

Comment: could you please provide me with a working code...i am trying to click on the element which is hidden in the navigation drawer...

Comment: android.widget.TextView is the classname in my case
how do i scroll and click on the element.

Comment: @RanjithHS as far as my research showed, scrolling methods have been deprecated, so UiScrollable will not work either. For scrolling purposes you can use swipe method